# How can I add a title to a field in the checkout page?

Tags: entities, commerce

I am wondering if there is a simple way (dropdown option or checkbox) to add a title to a field in the Drupal Commerce checkout page.  Specifically, I want the second field for Street Address to have the label: Address line 2.

> [image: screenshot]

I was unable to find this field in *Admin > Structure > View* that allows the option to "Manage Display" or "Manage Form Display" and make a label for a field "Hidden" or otherwise.

I also looked in the Commerce sections to no avail.

Next step is to find out if there is a *Billing Information > "Manage Form Display* menu somewhere.

Not in 
Home > Administration > Configuration > People > Profiles > Profile types  > Edit Customer > Manage fields 
either.

Comment: Please be aware that we do not provide tutorials or step-by-step instructions for achieving functionality from a description, screenshot or other website, as explained in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead explain your attempt(s), and be as complete as possible. What have you tried, what did you expect, what actually happened? If you have any code to include in the question, please add it. The more complete you are, the better we can formulate an answer.

Comment: I am not looking for a tutorial, more so for a menu or option that I am not yet aware of.  *Original post re-worded to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in User Interface (via link or menu or whatever). But if you use the following code in a module, you can add a title to your form element:

```
<?php
function CUSTOM_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // You should probably check for a form_id in here, as this runs on every form.
  // Below you will need to find the part of the $form array that has the billing address.
  $form['[see note above]']['widget'][0]['address']['address_line2']['#title'] = t('Address 2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line of the address field has an invisible title. It's explicitly set by the [Address](https://www.drupal.org/project/Address) module.

You can see that in action here: cgit.drupalcode.org/address/tree/src/Element/Address.php?h=272a7ce#n231

```
// Hide the label for the second address line.
if (isset($element['address_line2'])) {
  $element['address_line2']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
}
```

You could use [`hook_element_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.4.x) to define new process or after_build callbacks.

```
function mytheme_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  $types['address']['#process'][] = ['\Drupal\mytheme\Element\Address', 'processAddress'];
}
```

Overriding the element:

```
namespace Drupal\mytheme\Element;

use \Drupal\address\Element\Address as DefaultAddress;
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
class Address extends DefaultAddress {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function processAddress(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $element = parent::processAddress($element, $form_state, $complete_form);
    unset($element['address_line2']['#title_display']);
    return $element;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is clumsy as it makes all form element labels visible, but ultimately gets the job done.

Using this theme and modifying specifically this template:
[DOrange_form-element-label.html.twig](https://github.com/AcroMedia/orange_starter/blob/8.x-1.x/templates/input/form-element-label.html.twig#L36)
with an additional conditional before the set classes statment:

```
{%- if title_display == 'invisible'-%}
  {%-
    set title_display = [
      'visible',
    ]
  -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that works on Commerce 2 and Drupal 10. We have to use a `process` because these are custom fields. In this example, I display a label for field `address_line2`, modify the `address_line1` label ans alter order of `family_name`

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_element_info_alter
 */
function custom_module_element_info_alter(array &$types) {

  if (isset($types['address'])) {
    $types['address']['#process'][] = '_custom_module_add_adress_label';
  }
}

/**
 * Process callback for address element.
 */
function _custom_module_add_adress_label(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
  $element['address_line1']['#title'] = t('Address');
  $element['address_line2']['#title_display'] = 'before';
  $element['address_line2']['#title'] = t('Building / Floor / Apt');
  $element['family_name']['#weight'] = -10;
  return $element;
}
```